# How to Break up large Javascript file with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I'm new to Javascript and therefore requireJS - I'm currently teaching myself using Openlayers 3 examples, of which, I've just been appending to one large JS file.  Seeing that this is becoming unruly very quickly, I read up about RequireJS and thought I should get into the habit of doing things right from the onset; 'which is where I've hit issues'.

[Not that I imagine it matters, but i'm using Asp.net MVC]
Basically, I wish to break the file up into smaller related modules e.g.

- Map  [which is used by all modules and initiates the base layer map]
- Draw [handles points / polygons etc. and is added to the map as
  another layer]
- Geolocation [contains geolocation functions for plotting]
- etc., etc.

...giving the flexibility to have all layers activated at once, or a select few with easy to manage JS code.

I have had several attempts at breaking this code up into such individual JS files, [map / draw / Geolocation] and all fail as I feel I'm not grasping the requireJS methodology (*so as not to confuse readers and myself further, I'm neglecting to add my attempts*).

Here is the basic code that works:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts",
    paths: {
        //jquery: "/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min",
        ol: [
            "http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.1/build/ol",
            "/lib/ol"
        ],
        domReady: "/lib/domReady"
    },
    //map: { main: { test: "/Modules/Test/scripts/test" } },
    //The shim section is to tell RequireJS about any dependencies your files have before they can be used.  
    //Here, we are saying if we call “ol” to load that module, we have to load “jquery” first.
    //shim: {
        //ol: ["jquery"]
    //},
    //packages: [
    //    {
    //name: 'test',
    //location: 'http://...
    //main: 'main'                
    //}]
});
```

File I wish to break-up:

```
define(["ol"], function (ol) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //****************
        //------MAP-------

        //Setup Map Base
        // creating the view
        var view = new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.8713, 45.6452]),
            zoom: 19
        });

        // creating the map
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            target: "map",
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }),
            view: view
        });

        //****************
        //-----DRAW------

        var features = new ol.Collection();
        var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({ features: features }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: "#ffcc33",
                    width: 2
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "#ffcc33"
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        featureOverlay.setMap(map);

        var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: features,
            // the SHIFT key must be pressed to delete vertices, so
            // that new vertices can be drawn at the same position
            // of existing vertices
            deleteCondition: function (event) {
                return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
                    ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
            }
        });
        map.addInteraction(modify);

        var draw; // global so we can remove it later
        function addInteraction() {
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: features,
                type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
        }

        var typeSelect = document.getElementById("type");


        /**
         * Let user change the geometry type.
         * @param {Event} e Change event.
         */
        typeSelect.onchange = function (e) {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
        };

        addInteraction();

        //****************
        //---GEOLOCATION---//

        // Common app code run on every page can go here
        // Geolocation marker
        var markerEl = document.getElementById("geolocation_marker");
        var marker = new ol.Overlay({
            positioning: "center-center",
            element: markerEl,
            stopEvent: false
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);

        // LineString to store the different geolocation positions. This LineString
        // is time aware.
        // The Z dimension is actually used to store the rotation (heading).
        var positions = new ol.geom.LineString([],
            /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryLayout} */ ("XYZM"));

        // Geolocation Control
        var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation( /** @type {olx.GeolocationOptions} */({
            projection: view.getProjection(),
            trackingOptions: {
                maximumAge: 10000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 600000
            }
        }));

        var deltaMean = 500; // the geolocation sampling period mean in ms

        // Listen to position changes
        geolocation.on("change", function (evt) {
            var position = geolocation.getPosition();
            var accuracy = geolocation.getAccuracy();
            var heading = geolocation.getHeading() || 0;
            var speed = geolocation.getSpeed() || 0;
            var m = Date.now();

            addPosition(position, heading, m, speed);

            var coords = positions.getCoordinates();
            var len = coords.length;
            if (len >= 2) {
                deltaMean = (coords[len - 1][3] - coords[0][3]) / (len - 1);
            }

            var html = [
                "Position: " + position[0].toFixed(2) + ", " + position[1].toFixed(2),
                "Accuracy: " + accuracy,
                "Heading: " + Math.round(radToDeg(heading)) + "&deg;",
                "Speed: " + (speed * 3.6).toFixed(1) + " km/h",
                "Delta: " + Math.round(deltaMean) + "ms"
            ].join("<br />");
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });

        geolocation.on("error", function () {
            alert("geolocation error");
            // FIXME we should remove the coordinates in positions
        });

        // convert radians to degrees
        function radToDeg(rad) {
            return rad * 360 / (Math.PI * 2);
        }

        // convert degrees to radians
        function degToRad(deg) {
            return deg * Math.PI * 2 / 360;
        }

        // modulo for negative values
        function mod(n) {
            return ((n % (2 * Math.PI)) + (2 * Math.PI)) % (2 * Math.PI);
        }

        function addPosition(position, heading, m, speed) {
            var x = position[0];
            var y = position[1];
            var fCoords = positions.getCoordinates();
            var previous = fCoords[fCoords.length - 1];
            var prevHeading = previous && previous[2];
            if (prevHeading) {
                var headingDiff = heading - mod(prevHeading);

                // force the rotation change to be less than 180°
                if (Math.abs(headingDiff) > Math.PI) {
                    var sign = (headingDiff >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
                    headingDiff = -sign * (2 * Math.PI - Math.abs(headingDiff));
                }
                heading = prevHeading + headingDiff;
            }
            positions.appendCoordinate([x, y, heading, m]);

            // only keep the 20 last coordinates
            positions.setCoordinates(positions.getCoordinates().slice(-20));

            // FIXME use speed instead
            if (heading && speed) {
                markerEl.src = "/OrchardLocal/Media/Default/Map/geolocation_marker.png"; //"data/geolocation_marker_heading.png";F:\DeleteMeThree\_Orchard-19x\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Cns.OL\Contents/Images/geolocation_marker.png
            } else {
                //alert(markerEl.src); PETE: Not sure if this is std OL practice, but this is achieved by already having an element
                //called "geolocation_marker" in the dom as an img, which this uses? Strange to me
                markerEl.src = "/OrchardLocal/Media/Default/Map/geolocation_marker.png"; //I added img via media module - ridiculous?!
            }
        }

        var previousM = 0;
        // change center and rotation before render
        map.beforeRender(function (map, frameState) {
            if (frameState !== null) {
                // use sampling period to get a smooth transition
                var m = frameState.time - deltaMean * 1.5;
                m = Math.max(m, previousM);
                previousM = m;
                // interpolate position along positions LineString
                var c = positions.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);
                var view = frameState.viewState;
                if (c) {
                    view.center = getCenterWithHeading(c, -c[2], view.resolution);
                    view.rotation = -c[2];
                    marker.setPosition(c);
                }
            }
            return true; // Force animation to continue
        });

        // recenters the view by putting the given coordinates at 3/4 from the top or
        // the screen
        function getCenterWithHeading(position, rotation, resolution) {
            var size = map.getSize();
            var height = size[1];

            return [
                position[0] - Math.sin(rotation) * height * resolution * 1 / 4,
                position[1] + Math.cos(rotation) * height * resolution * 1 / 4
            ];
        }

        // postcompose callback
        function render() {
            map.render();
        }

        //EMP
        //$("#geolocate").click(function () {
        //    alert("JQuery Running!");
        //});

        // geolocate device
        var geolocateBtn = document.getElementById("geolocate");
        geolocateBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            geolocation.setTracking(true); // Start position tracking

            map.on("postcompose", render);
            map.render();

            disableButtons();
        }, false);
    });
})
```

Considering that i'll have many more modules to attach in the future, what would be the best way to break-up this code using RequireJS for efficiency and coding functionality / maintenance.

Thanks ever so much for your guidance / thoughts, cheers WL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every require module (`defined using define`) is supposed to return a `function/object`. The breakup shown in question doesn't, instead just splits the code. Think of some hypothetical module buckets and put each piece of code (or function) into a module. Then group the code into a `require js` module and return the module's interface.

Let me try to explain further with an example.

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#heyINeedMap").click(function(){
    require(['map'],function(Map){
      Map.render($target);
    });  
  });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  require(['map','geolocation'],function(Map,Geolocation){
      window.App.start = true;
      window.App.map = Map;              //won't suggest, but you can do.
      window.App.geolocation = Geolocation; 

      //do something.
      $("#lastCoords").click(function(){
        var coords = App.geolocation.getLastSavedCoords();
        if(!!coords){
          coords = App.geolocation.fetchCurrentCoords();
        }
        alert(coords);
      });
  });
});
```

**map.js**

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
  var privateVariableAvailableToAllMapInstances = 'something';
  var mapType = 'scatter';
  return function(){
    render: function(el){
      //rendering logic goes here
    },
    doSomethingElse: function(){
      privateVariable = 'some new value';
      //other logic goes here
    },
    changeMapType: function(newType){
      mapType = newType;
      //...
    }
  }
});
```

**geolocation.js**

```
//Just assuming that it needs jquery & another module called navigation to work.
define(['jquery','navigation'], function($,Gnav){
  return {
    var coordinates = Gnav.lastSavedCoords;
    fetchCurrentCoords: function(){
      //coordinates = [79.12213, 172.12342];  //fetch from API/something
      return coordinates;
    },
    getLastSavedCoords: function(){
      return coordinates;
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this gives an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply...forgive my ineptness, I've no doubt your concept's sound but due to my fresh JS sensibility I'm a little perplexed with your example. I've never come across a function that returns what appears to be an array of nameless/identifier-less functions before? So sorry to be a pain, but could you elaborate slightly further with your example re: map.js [...and trying not to be too cheeky - as I'm very grateful for any example/pseudo I can get - but possibly relating to map.js with 'draw' functionality to give me some perspective]? Thanks in advance WL

Comment: assume `render` to named `draw`

Comment: I'm interested in the same concept but can't see how this answers or solves the original OP's desires? It appears this would just substitute their already large file with another [map.js] but partitioned into functions -- which I can't get to work as per OP's follow up question: incorrect syntax with comma delimited functions and that they all don’t have 'Expected Identifiers' -- are we missing something, and is it possible to breakup/encapsulate such code into separate javascript files, yet still access the OL and map var in this case? Cheers

Comment: it's not exactly into functions but modules which can return either functions or objects as per one's understanding.

Comment: Further elaborated the answer, hope so it helps.

Comment: Ah, I see - the original Map.js with the return "function"(){....,...,} had me stumped, but once I removed 'function' as per Geolocation.js all went well as per the rest of your solution. Thanks a lot coding_idiot :)